# Prove $E[\max_{1\le i\le n}\frac{|X_i|}{\sqrt{n}}]\to 0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid real valued random variables with finite variance. Is it true that $E[\max_{1\le i\le n}\frac{|X_i|}{\sqrt{n}}]\to 0$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Near duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/396134/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $L^2$-convergence implies $L^1$-convergence, it suffices to show that

$$\frac{1}{n} \mathbb{E} \left( \max_{i=1,\ldots,n} X_i^2 \right) \to 0 \qquad \text{as} \, \, n \to \infty. \tag{1}$$

To this end, recall that the equality

$$\mathbb{E} Y = \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Y \geq r) \, dr$$

holds for any non-negative random variable $Y$. For $Y:= \max_{i=1,\ldots,n} X_i^2$ we obtain

$$\frac{1}{n} \mathbb{E} \left( \max_{i=1,\ldots,n} X_i^2 \right) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}  \mathbb{P} \left( \max_{i=1,\ldots,n} X_i^2 \geq r \right) \, dr.$$

Since

$$f_n(r) := \frac{1}{n} \mathbb{P} \left( \max_{i=1,\ldots,n} X_i^2 \geq r \right) \leq \frac{1}{n} \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n \{X_i^2 \geq r\} \right) \leq \mathbb{P}(X_1^2 \geq r) =: f(r),$$

$f_n \to 0$ (as $|f_n| \leq \frac{1}{n}$) and

$$\int_0^{\infty} f(r) \, dr = \mathbb{E}(X_1^2)<\infty$$

it follows from the dominated convergence theorem that

$$\frac{1}{n} \mathbb{E} \left( \max_{i=1,\ldots,n} X_i^2 \right) = \int_0^{\infty} f_n(r) \, dr \to 0 \qquad \text{as} \, \, n \to \infty.$$

This proves $(1)$.