# Convergence of the supremum of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I've a question regarding the convergence of the supremum of random variables. Assume $X_1, X_2, ...$ are i.i.d. and positive with $\mathbb{E}[X_i^4] < \infty$. Does $\sup\limits_{i=1, ..., n} \frac{X_i}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow 0$ hold (in probability)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1180488/) it was shown that (under the given assumptions) $\sup_{i=1,\ldots,n} \frac{X_i}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ in $L^1$. Since $L^1$-convergence implies (by Markov's inequality) convergence in probability, the claim follows.